# Finding effective way to fetch data from mongo db

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to fetch data from mongodb by using document property similarly like findById() method I can fetch with query but I want to display data on another page

This is my api code for fetching data

```js
const User = require("../models/User");
const Image = require("../models/Image");

const addImage = async (req, res, next) => {
  const newImage = new Image({ userId: req.user.id, ...req.body });
  try {
    const saveImage = await newImage.save();
    res.status(200).json("Image uploaded");
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};

// GETPRODUCTBYID :-

const getImage = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const image = await Image.findById(req.params.id);
    res.status(200).json(image);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};

// GET ALL PRODUCTS :-

const getAllImages = async (req, res) => {
  const qNew = req.query.new;
  const qCategory = req.query.category;
  const qBrand = req.query.brand;
  try {
    let images;

    if (qNew) {
      images = await Image.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 }).limit(1);
    } else if (qCategory) {
      images = await Image.find({
        categories: { $in: [qCategory] },
      });
    }
    if (qBrand) {
      images = await Image.find({ brand: "Honda" });
    } else {
      images = await Image.find();
    }

    res.status(200).json(images);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};

// GET IMAGES BY BRAND :-

const getImagesByBrand = async (req, res) => {
  const qBrand = req.query.brand;
  try {
    const images = await Image.find( {brand: qBrand});
    res.status(200).json(images);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};

module.exports = Object.freeze({
  addImage,
  getImage,
  getImagesByBrand,
  getAllImages,
});
```

Structure of document in mongo db

- Document
- _id
- brand

I want to fetch data with brand property and show it on new page it is possible?